# Sending image file from MySql to android using JSON.- File not passed

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

****This question refers to passing file from MySQL, not from URL. So Please check carefully if you are willing to tag it as duplicate****

I am trying to pass an image (stored as BLOB) from MySQL to android via php.In PHP I am doing:

```
function getimage($id)
{
     $sql = "SELECT mime,data, evimagename FROM evidence
    WHERE transactionID = :transactionID";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(":transactionID" => $id));
    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $mime);
    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->bindColumn(3, $imgname);

     $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

     return array("mime" => $mime,
         "data" => $data,"imgname"=>$imgname);
}
```

And Calling this function as:

```
   $result = $blobObj->selectBlob($trid);
   $file= $result['data'];
   header("Content-Type:application/json");
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Expires: 0');
   $filename = $a['imgname'];
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename.".jpeg");
   $encoded = base64_encode($file);
   echo json_encode(array('image'=>$encoded));
```

In android, I am trying to get this json_encoded file as:

```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://10.1.1.5/connect/getevimage.php");

        try {

            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
            String trid = arg0[0];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TRID", trid));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String responsestring = content.toString();

            Log.d("chddeck",responsestring);
            long filesize = response.getEntity().getContentLength();
            Log.d("filesize",String.valueOf(filesize));
```

In my logbook, I can see the responsestring as

```
org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@41a2fc58
```

and size of the file as -1.
I searched A Lot, but couldn't find any clues. Can you please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: did u get blob data?..whats the size declared for blog in db?? and why only u wanna store as blog ..alternative can be direct upload on server and fetch the path of it

Comment: @DIVA, running the page in browser, I can get the blob data downloaded in local folder. But I m not getting blob in android.I am using MEDIUMBLOB, so the file size, 500KB should not be problem. AND, some function requires editing image file and updating in server. Thats why I am directly updating in mysql.

Comment: ok that way also alternative method i told is much safer ..anyways the issue i noticed can be u r tring to convert response in string but string have some limit so be ur blog cannot be completely converted into string hence just try to read from file u downloaded and convert that to image

Comment: @DIVA, I could've done as you said, grabbing from the URL(direct server), but I am worried the application can be cracked easily and people can have a look on the passing URL. Or can you share any link that gives safe file getting from server ??

Comment: there are many ways to handle it ..like encrytion..

Comment: did u solve the issue?

Comment: @DIVA, I couldnt find the  missing part or error in this code, but ultimately, I started storing file in server and path in mysql. Although not very efficient "as my requirement", but I will do as so until I can figure it out.

Comment: For confused other users, this user, I am replying to, has username DIVA previously.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative method can be

**Method 1:**

using path of image, since blog data somethimes may be big enought to get in string variable and hence that may be corrupted since u hvnt received complete blog in string variable...

**Method 2 :**

Using lib for direct upload image on server

small code snip :

```
mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));
mFtpClient.login(user, password);
mFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(serverRoad);
mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
BufferedInputStream buffIn=null;
buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
mFtpClient.storeFile("test.txt", buffIn);
buffIn.close();
mFtpClient.logout();
mFtpClient.disconnect();
```

[Link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)